# How to continue ps to create folder based upon first 3 characters of file name

Tags: powershell

I would like a powershell script that would move files into a folder based upon the date of the file and then move into subfolders based upon the first 3 characters of the file names.
I have been able to move the files to a dated folder, but do not know how to continue with powershell to create subfolders and move files to correct date subfolder.  This is what I have and is working for the date:

```
Get-ChildItem \\servername\path\path\path\path\New_folder\*.* -Recurse |     foreach { 
$x = $_.LastWriteTime.ToShortDateString()
$new_folder_name = Get-Date $x -Format yyMMdd
$des_path = "\\servername\path\path\path\path\$new_folder_name"

if (test-path $des_path){ 
move-item $_.fullname $des_path 
} else {
new-item -ItemType directory -Path $des_path
move-item $_.fullname $des_path 
}
}
```

Comment: You could have a look at the `.SubString()` method of string objects. ;-) Here are some hopefully helpful links: [link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7.2) [link2](https://4sysops.com/archives/strings-in-powershell-replace-compare-concatenate-split-substring/)

Comment: Thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `SubString()` method you can extract a particular part of a given string:

```
$SourcePath = '\\servername\path\path\path\path\New_folder'
$DestinationRoot = '\\servername\path\path\path\path'
Get-ChildItem $SourcePath -Recurse -File |
    ForEach-Object { 
        $timeStamp = Get-Date $( $_.LastWriteTime) -Format 'yyMMdd'
        $FirstThreeLettersFromFileName = $_.BaseName.SubString(0,3)
        $destinationPath = "$DestinationRoot\$timeStamp\$FirstThreeLettersFromFileName"

        if (-not (Test-Path -Path $destinationPath)) { 
            New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $destinationPath
        }
        Move-Item -Path $_.fullname -Destination $destinationPath 
    }
```

Comment: `$_.LastWriteTime` is already a [datetime], you could build in one step with the [-format operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html) `$destinationPath = "{0}\{1:yyMMdd}\{2}" -f $DestinationRoot,$_.LastWriteTime,$_.BaseName`

Comment: I wanted to keep it a little more basic for Shirley.  ;-)